# Unable to get Jenkins working with Satis repo

Tags: jenkins, composer-php, bitbucket, satis

I'm having an issue with Jenkins and Satis whereby I receive the following error

```
[ErrorException]          
Undefined variable: auth
```

when Jenkins tries to install the package from Satis.  Obviously there is something wrong with authentication, but I can't figure out what. I've setup my ssh keys with bitbucket (where the repo is) for the jenkins user, and restarted jenkins.

I know there is an auth.json file that can be used, but that stores basic auth information in plaintext, which I don't really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key lies in making sure:

Jenkins has its ssh keys right

Bitbucket is a known host.

no password on the private key.

When you build the satis repo, build it with the -n option

Make sure Bitbucket has Jenkins' public key

That should about do it, so anyone else with this issue, take note and leave a comment here.

Comment: I'd also like to add something as it tripped me up. If you're using keys, check your repository urls in composer, ensure they're "git@bitbucket:vendor/repo" rather than https!